# How to prevent re-render cycle when using onchange handler? when input changes state updates and component re-renders. So I am not able to edit input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import classes from './List.module.css';


const List = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData([...props.data]);
  }, [props.data]);

  const emailHandler = (event, id) => {
    let ind = data.findIndex(el => el.id === id);
    let updatedData = [...data]
    updatedData[ind].input = event.target.value;
    setData(updatedData);
  }

  console.log("hello")

  return (
    <div className="table-responsive">
      <table className="table" onMouseLeave={props.saveUpdate}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Phone</th>
            <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope='col'>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((el, ind) => <tr key={el.id}>
            <td onClick={() => props.redirect(el.id)}>{el.first_name + ' ' + el.last_name}</td>
            <td>{el.mobile ?? 'NA'}</td>
            <td>{el.phone ?? 'NA'}</td>
            <td className={classes.last_td} >
              {el.editable ? <input className='form-control-sm' type="email" value={el.email} onChange={(e) => emailHandler(e, el.id)} /> : <span className={classes.email} >{el.email}</span>}
            </td>
            <td><div className='ml-2'><i role='button' className="las la-user-edit" onClick={props.enableEdit.bind(this, el.id)} ></i> <i role='button' className="las la-trash-alt" onClick={props.del.bind(this, el.id)} ></i></div> </td>
          </tr>)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )

}

export default List;
```

Comment: Side note: There's no reason to pass your `emailHandler` an `id` that it has to look up in `data`. You're creating a function for every entry in the list anyway, just pass it the object directly. If you don't want to do that, store the `id` on the element as a `data-*` attribute and then reuse the same `emailHandler` for each entry in the list.

Comment: In general, avoid copying props to state (your `useEffect` handler), [details here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html). In general, either make the component controlled (calls the parent to update its props when something changes) or uncontrolled (doesn't get its state from the parent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rerender is expected when the state changes.

But, it seems you are updating `el.input` but then using `el.email` in the input box.

```html
<input className='form-control-sm' type="email" value={el.email} onChange={(e) => emailHandler(e, el.id)} />
```

Instead you can try using the same value:

```html
<input className='form-control-sm' type="email" value={el.input} onChange={(e) => emailHandler(e, el.id)} />
```

Also, you might want to make sure that your props are not changing while you are using this component, as it would reset the state, hence reseting the input value to its initial value.

If you want to only allow this at mount, you can get rid of the following code:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData([...props.data]);
  }, [props.data]);
```

And instead simply do:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);

// no `useEffect`
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you help me? I have a data stored in redux store. I want to use that data in my functional component by adding some new properties to it. I have done this using useEffect. Now I also want to auto save the data to redux store using useEffect. But the problem is the first useEffect that I used for mapping is depend on redux state and the second useeffect is updating the redux state. So the component is re-rendering inifinitely. Please help me. What to do? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: As pointed out by other comment, it seems that your pain point is that you have both a local state (`useState`) and a Redux store that provides a competing state via the props. You should only use one single state which would make your component _controlled_ (by redux state). You would have no effects at all, just redux state read from the props, and updated via app event that dispatch some actions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Your answers helping me a lot. As I am new to React and don't know much. I have data stored on redux. And I have options like search, sort and edit. As I understand you are saying that I don't need to mantain state, I just have to directly manuplate the data from redux store. So for every change, Is it good to fetch data from redux? Please help me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is not the place for me to teach you redux but if you know how to use redux, you know how to read and write state in your component. Use this for any state that is shared between multiple components. For a state that is only used inside one component, using `useState` is simpler and usually more performant. Good luck and don't give up!